# Setting height in percent

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have rewritten this question to reflect the information people have asked.

First, if you go to

http://www.backcountryskitours.com/NEW/SKI%20TOURS%20IN%20THE%20SIERRA%20NEVADA/pages/tours/0312_tours/0312_tour.htm

you will see nearly exactly what I want. For widescreens and tablets it is exactly what I want. You can see the descriptive part in the left column and the map in the right column. Being able to see the two simultaneously is important for use of the information. The height of both of these s is fixed.

For small devices such as a phone, the map is placed under the description. I reduce the height of the  for the description. Right now, the  for the map is fixed and is too large for it to be entirely viewed along with the description on a cell phone.

What I want is for in the narrow, phone, case, the height of the map to be automatically scaled to fill whatever is the remaining vertical space. Using “auto” does not work because it scales the height of the  to fit the contents, not the space available.

I have tried using percents for the heights (25% for the description and 60% for the map). That does not work. It should work, but I may have a problem because those are percentages of the container not percentages of the screen, and the two s are not in the same container.

I’m using Bootstrap 3.

Do you know how to make this work for me?

Here is the code for a scaled down version, i.e. less description than in the final version. Skip to bottom to CSS information.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="set_margin_col1"> <img class="img-responsive" src="../../../assets/logos/skitours_title_756w.gif" alt="Logo"> </div>
                <div class="tour_title">Andesite Peak </div>
                <div id="description" class="set_margin_col1">
                    <p class="des_section"><br>
                Summary &nbsp;<a href="../../general/summary.htm"><img src="../../../assets/icons/info_icon_3.png" alt="Link to more information about summary" width="13" height="13" style="margin-top: -2px" title="Link to more information about summary"></a></p>
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td class="summary_left_col">Difficulty</td>
                            <td class="summary_right_col"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="difficulty" --><strong>3</strong> Intermediate<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="summary_left_col">Length</td>
                            <td class="summary_right_col"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="length" -->4.6 miles round trip<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="summary_left_col">Starting<br>
                            Elevation</td>
                            <td class="summary_right_col"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="start_elev" -->7200 feet<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="summary_left_col">Cumulative<br>
                            Elevation<br>
                            Change</td>
                            <td class="summary_right_col"><!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="cum_elev" -->+1000, -1000 round trip<!-- InstanceEndEditable --></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <p class="des_section"> Description  &nbsp; <a href="../../general/description.htm"><img src="../../../assets/icons/info_icon_3.png" alt="Link to more information about description" width="13" height="13" style="margin-top: -2px" title="Link to more information about description"></a></p>
                <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="tour_description" -->
                <p class="des_paragraph">Andesite Peak is a dramatic setting for a snack or lunch. The peak is the high point on Andesite Ridge, overlooks Castle Valley to the east, and has a primo panoramic view that includes Castle Peak.</p>
                <p class="des_paragraph">The tour described here is the easiest route to the summit. More adventurous skiers can follow the more direct Andesite Ridge and Peak tour. This tour can also be turned into<span style="font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif"> a loop as described in the Andesite Ridge Loop tour.</span></p>
                <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->
                <p class="des_section">Mileage Log  &nbsp; <a href="../../general/mileage_log.htm"><img src="../../../assets/icons/info_icon_3.png" alt="Link to more information about mileage log" width="13" height="13" style="margin-top: -2px" title="Link to more information about mileage log"></a><br>
                    <span class="des_numbers">Numbers in parentheses<br>
                correspond to mileage points on map</span></p>
                <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="mileage_log" -->
                <p id="WP_1" class="des_paragraph"><span class="des_route_segment">Waypoint 1 to 2</span><br>
                Miles: <span class="des_mileage_elevation">0.0 - 0.3</span><br>
                Elevation change: <span class="des_mileage_elevation">+100 feet</span>&nbsp;</p>
                <p class="des_paragraph">From the <span class="des_points">trailhead (1)</span> ski east on the snow-covered road that parallels the interstate and then northwest for a total of 0.3 mile until you reach a <span class="des_points">road junction (2)</span>. The road continuing northwest (straight) leads to Castle Valley, which is closed to snowmobile use, while this tour follows the road to the west (left).&nbsp;</p>
                <!-- InstanceEndEditable --> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="menu_wrapper" class="set_margin_col2"> <span class="menu_bar">Find Tours Using &nbsp;<a href="../../find_tours/find_index.htm" title="Link to index of tours" target="_self">INDEX</a>&nbsp; <a href="../../find_tours/find_map.htm" title="Link to interactive map of tours" target="_self">MAP</a> &nbsp;  |  &nbsp; <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="profile" --><a href="0312_profile.htm" title="Link to elevation profile of tour" target="_self">Profile</a><!-- InstanceEndEditable --> &nbsp; | &nbsp; <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="description" --><a href="#" title="Link to description of tour" target="_self">Description</a><!-- InstanceEndEditable --> &nbsp; | &nbsp; <!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="map" --><a href="#" title="Link to map of tour" target="_self">Map</a><!-- InstanceEndEditable --> &nbsp; | &nbsp;<!-- InstanceBeginEditable name="waypoinnts" --> <a href="#" title="Link to waypoint data for tour" target="_self">Waypoints</a><!-- InstanceEndEditable -->&nbsp;<a href="../../general/menu.htm"><img src="../../../assets/icons/info_icon_3.png" alt="Link to more information about menu" width="13" height="13" style="margin-top: -2px" title="Link to more information about menu"></a></span> </div>
            <div id="myContainer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="footer">
                <p><!-- #BeginLibraryItem "/library/copyright.lbi" --><a href="../../general/copyright.htm">© 2020 Marcus Libkind</a><!-- #EndLibraryItem -->&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;|&nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="../../general/disclaimer.htm" title="Link to disclaimer" target="_self"> Disclaimer</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;|&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" title="Link to contact form" target="_self">Contact</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;|&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<span class="des_section">Hosted&nbsp;by&nbsp;<a href="https://www.snowlands.org" title="Link to Snowlands Network" target="_self">Snowlands&nbsp;Network</a></span></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The default CSS for the description and map (myContainer) is:

```
#description {
height: 510px;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
overflow: auto;
padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
}
#myContainer {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 560px;
background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

For small devices the @media rules in the CSS are given below. The height for #description has been reduced dramatically, but for #myContainer it has been reduced only a bit and is still fixed. What do I do to make myContainer fill the available vertical space, but not be bigger than the available vertical space?

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
#description {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
}
#myContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe tag it with `bootstrap` so the back-enders can join in on the fun as well (as your question concerns that). I would consider `grid` or `flexbox` for this, which would solve all your issues and reduce your code complexity a lot - including removing all that wacky class-named `div`itis.

Comment: Can you post some of your HTML code so we can see how its all laid out?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that is pretty good. Instead of setting the height in percents, which does not work, one can set it in percent of the viewport height. I use xxxvh instead of xxx%.